# Lambda to get sum and single value from same child

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a problem with this query trying to get a sum and a single value from the same child

Class 1

```
class Project{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SubProject> SubProjects { get; set; }
}
```

Class 2

```
class SubProject{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Week> Weeks { get; set; }
}
```

Class 3

```
class Week{
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
}
```

what i'm trying to do is get all weeks, within a range, for a Project in a new list of classes like this

```
class ProjectOverview{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProjectWeekOverview> Weeks { get; set; }
}
class ProjectWeekOverview{
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public int TotalHours { get; set; }
}
```

i have tried something like this, but i cant manage to get in the week for it also, if what i done this far is even correct

```
List<Project> projects = { List.Of.Projects };
List<ProjectOverview> overview = projects
    .Select(p => new ProjectOverview
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Name = p.Name,
        Weeks = p
            .SubProjects
            .Select(sp => new ProjectWeekOverview
            {
                Week = ????,
                TotalHours = sp
                    .Where(w => w.Week >= 30 && w.Week <= 35)
                    .Sum(w => w.Hours)
            })
    })
    .ToList();
```

anyone that can help with this?

**Edit**: a subproject can contain multiple week items with the same week like, to store hours from different action how long they took

```
week { week = 10, hours = 3 }
week { week = 10, hours = 4 }
week { week = 11, hours = 3 }
```

so what i want is to have the week property to a set week, and the totalhours to sum of all hours in that week

Comment: You could also use the syntactic sugar LINQ.

Comment: Which one of the weeks do you want? The earliest, the first (in your collection), a random one...?

Comment: @Tobias i want to get overview in a range of weeks, so it could be all, could be none

Comment: @trembon I'm not sure that is very clear.  In the example you gave, you are trying to sum the hours for 6 separate weeks, but you only have a single week `int`.  What value do you want in that property?

Comment: @psubsee2003 sorry, seems like the question wasnt clear, added more details in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to GroupBy week, and have Week as the key and Sum as item.

Give this a try. The output is an anonymous type, must have to convert it to whatever type you want as result. Its the grouping that matters.

```
        List<Project> projects = null;

        var weeksAndHours = projects
            .Select(p => new 
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                Weeks = p
                    .SubProjects.SelectMany(sp => sp.Weeks)
                    .Where(w => w.Week >= 30 && w.Week <= 35)
                    .GroupBy(w => w.Week)
                    .Select(g => new { week = g.Key, hours = g.Sum( w=> w.Hours) })
            });
```

Comment: I suppose this will be used against Linq to Objects and not Linq to Entities, right? In the meantime I copypaste a solution to have some example code for you.